# Postgres: Calculate ratio of table entries that match condition

Tags: database, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have the following two tables in a PostgreSQL database:

```
dummy=# select * from employee;
 id | name  
----+-------
  1 | John
  2 | Susan
  3 | Jim
  4 | Sarah
(4 rows)

dummy=# select * from stats;
 id | arrival  |    day     | employee_id 
----+----------+------------+-------------
  2 | 08:31:34 | monday     |           2
  4 | 08:15:00 | monday     |           3
  5 | 08:43:00 | monday     |           4
  1 | 08:34:00 | monday     |           1
  7 | 08:29:00 | midweek    |           1
  8 | 08:31:00 | midweek    |           2
  9 | 08:10:00 | midweek    |           3
 10 | 08:40:00 | midweek    |           4
 11 | 08:28:00 | midweek    |           1
 12 | 08:33:00 | midweek    |           2
 14 | 08:21:00 | midweek    |           3
 15 | 08:45:00 | midweek    |           4
 16 | 08:25:00 | midweek    |           1
 17 | 08:35:00 | midweek    |           2
 18 | 08:44:00 | midweek    |           4
 19 | 08:10:00 | friday     |           1
 20 | 08:40:00 | friday     |           2
 21 | 08:30:00 | friday     |           3
 22 | 08:30:00 | friday     |           4
(19 rows)
```

I want to select all employees that arrive between `8:25` and `8:35` on `midweek` and `friday`. I can accomplish that relatively easy with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM stats
WHERE
    arrival >= (time '8:30' - interval '5 minutes')
AND
    arrival <= (time '8:30' + interval '5 minutes')
AND
    (day = 'midweek' or day = 'friday');
```

However, an additional criterion is that I only want to select those employees that arrive at least 60% of the time within the aforementioned time window. This is where I am stuck. I do not know how to calculate that ratio.

What does the Query look like which fulfills all the criteria?

**CLARIFICATION**

Apparently the above description for the ratio is misleading.
When calculating the ratio then only the rows that meet the criteria `(day = 'midweek' or day = 'friday')` shall be considered. So in the sample data John and Susan show up four times for work on `midweek` and `friday`. Three out of those four times they are punctual. Hence, the ratio for Susan and John is `75%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a common table expression to calculate needed counts, e.g.

```
with in_time as (
    select * 
    from stats
    where arrival >= (time '8:30' - interval '5 minutes')
    and arrival <= (time '8:30' + interval '5 minutes')
    and (day = 'midweek' or day = 'friday')
),
count_in_time as (
    select employee_id, count(*)
    from in_time
    group by employee_id
),
total_count as (
    select employee_id, count(*)
    from stats
    where day = 'midweek' or day = 'friday'
    group by employee_id
)
select 
    i.*, 
    c.count as in_time, 
    t.count as total_count, 
    round(c.count* 100.0/t.count, 2) as ratio
from in_time i
join count_in_time c using(employee_id) 
join total_count t using(employee_id);
```

Results:

```
 id | arrival  |   day   | employee_id | in_time | total_count | ratio 
----+----------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+-------
 16 | 08:25:00 | midweek |           1 |       3 |           4 | 75.00
 11 | 08:28:00 | midweek |           1 |       3 |           4 | 75.00
  7 | 08:29:00 | midweek |           1 |       3 |           4 | 75.00
 17 | 08:35:00 | midweek |           2 |       3 |           4 | 75.00
 12 | 08:33:00 | midweek |           2 |       3 |           4 | 75.00
  8 | 08:31:00 | midweek |           2 |       3 |           4 | 75.00
 21 | 08:30:00 | friday  |           3 |       1 |           3 | 33.33
 22 | 08:30:00 | friday  |           4 |       1 |           4 | 25.00
(8 rows)
```

You can add an appropriate condition in the WHERE clause of the final query.

If you want to get aggregated data only with employees and their ratios, use count() with filter:

```
select employee_id, name, in_time* 1.0/ total as ratio
from (
    select 
        employee_id,
        count(*) filter (where arrival >= time '8:30' - interval '5 minutes' and arrival <= time '8:30' + interval '5 minutes') as in_time,
        count(*) as total
    from stats
    where day in ('midweek', 'friday')
    group by 1
    ) s
join employee e on e.id = s.employee_id
where in_time* 1.0/ total >= 0.6;

 employee_id | name  |         ratio          
-------------+-------+------------------------
           1 | John  | 0.75000000000000000000
           2 | Susan | 0.75000000000000000000
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not know how to extract the information I want from the results. It should simply print out John and Susan and their id. I tried adding `WHERE ratio > 0.6` after the `JOIN` statements but this just returned an error that column ratio does not exist. Sorry if this is a trivial task but I am not a database guy and I have only recently started to scratch the surface of PostgreSQL.

Comment: The first query gives you detail data like in the question. Of course, you can get aggregated data in a simpler query like the second my query.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the arrival rate like so, for example:

```
SELECT name, 
AVG(CASE WHEN arrival >= (time '8:30' - interval '5 minutes') AND
        arrival <= (time '8:30' + interval '5 minutes') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS arrival_rate
    FROM employee
    INNER JOIN stats ON stats.employee_id = employee.id
    GROUP BY name
```

and to select only those where rate > 60% you just use having condition

```
    SELECT name, 
    AVG(CASE WHEN arrival >= (time '8:30' - interval '5 minutes') AND
            arrival <= (time '8:30' + interval '5 minutes') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS arrival_rate
        FROM employee
        INNER JOIN stats ON stats.employee_id = employee.id
        GROUP BY name

        HAVING 

 AVG(CASE WHEN arrival >= (time '8:30' - interval '5 minutes') AND
            arrival <= (time '8:30' + interval '5 minutes') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)


         > 0.6
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not quite clear on the requirement for the calculation of the ratio earlier. I updated the question to clarify how the ratio/arrival_rate should be calculated.